# How this code is vulnerable to command injection CWE 7?

Tags: java

how to mitigate this vulnerability for command injection.

```
protected String runcmd(String cmd) {
    String line;
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            ret.append(line);
        }
        input.close();
        p.waitFor();
```

Comment: What makes you think the code is vulnerable?  Have you identified a specific vulnerability, and if so can you show what solutions you've attempted to fix it?

Comment: I use VCG static analyzer on SDN controller source code, this was indicated as software vulnerability. I want other members feed back about this finding that help me regarding to this code

Comment: @RichieThomas as I mentioned in my answer below, this may have a few potential vulnerabilities but it all depends on the general setup and the context in which this code runs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this really depends on several parameters you're not mentioning, such as when this piece of code gets executed, the privileges of the user running the java application and so on.

For example, consider the following. You're running this piece of code, within the context of a web application which itself is running on administrative privileges. Suppose, also that the `runcmd` method can be executed with the `cmd` argument being procured through user input.

Since you perform no kind of validation for the passed in argument, a malicious user could potentially inject a command to interact with your underlying system in a way you would not want.

Comment: this was indicated by VCG static analysis tool i perform on SDN controller source code. according to VCG and CWE it is a vulnerability can you help me to explain what is the flaw in this code